# Should I install the intel graphic driver after installed nvidia driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel, thinkpad

My laptop is w540 with ubuntu 14.04.2 kernel 3.18.9, Nvidia k2100m and intel hd 4600, I preferred the closed-source drivers, so I have already installed the Nvidia 349 driver from PPA. To better use the intel graphic, should I installed the intel one then?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any problems: no, you don't!  Let the automatic system updates take care of it.

If you have problems with your display, yes, you do!                          !                        !

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask